# partial mocking of methods of concrete class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

```
  BTPhysicalAccount testerInstance = new BTPhysicalAccount(IvirtualAccounts, BTmarketIn, int);
```

I want to test a method of this class. that BTmarketIn is a concrete class and a method in this class is used in that method under test. So I needed to mock that method hence i tried this:

```
        var readerAsk = Substitute.ForPartsOf<BTMarketInfo>();
        readerAsk.When(x => x.GetAskPrice(Arg.Any<SymbolType>())).DoNotCallBase();
        readerAsk.GetAskPrice(Arg.Any<SymbolType>()).Returns(2000);
        readerAsk.When(x => x.GetBidPrice(Arg.Any<SymbolType>())).DoNotCallBase();
        readerAsk.GetBidPrice(Arg.Any<SymbolType>()).Returns(2000);
```

it kept throwing null exception error and after some research I realized that you cannot mock non-virtual methods.
So I do have an interface class of that BTMarketIn class IMarketInfo. Now I can mock an instance of this interface but I need an instance of BTMarketIn to pass as constructor argument. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you refactor to pass an `IMarketInfo` into whatever constructor you're referring to?  Currently, it sounds like `BTMarketInfo` and the class you're testing are tightly coupled.  If you can refactor the target class to take an `IMarketInfo` into the constructor rather than a `BTMarketInfo`, you'll be in better shape.

Comment: Nope refactoring is not an option, otherwise I could simply make methods virtual and mock them. Is there no other way?

Comment: You could possibly use Microsoft Fakes Shims:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx#shims.  I don't have any experience with them, but I think this is the use case they're intended for.

Comment: Thank you. It really worked.

Comment: Glad it worked.  I've posted the comment as an answer so that you can accept it to close out the question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft Fakes Shims should work for this:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx#shims